# dapper "IN" clause not working with multiple values

Tags: dapper

**Scenario:**

I have a string property in my model that holds the IDs from a `MultiSelectList @Html.ListBox`. If I select two list items, my property value will look like this `0100,0500`.

**The problem:**

Dapper where clause will only work with a single value:

```
CODE IN (@SomeCode) // for example, 0100 or 0500 returns results
CODE IN (@SomeCode) // 0100,0500 does not return results.
```

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 17):

That's because you don't need to tell Dapper to use parenthesis `()`. It will do fine by its own. Try this:

```
var codes = new List<string> { "0100","0500"};
var sql = "select * from SomeTable where CODE IN @codes";
var items = connection.Query(sql, new { codes });
```

Comment: This was one of the strangest issues I have faced recently. I was getting "incorrect syntax near ','" -error and couldn't figure out what was wrong as the SQL-syntax and parameter-binding seemed to be correct. After finding this answer and removing parenthesis (@ids) to simply @ids this error was resolved. Really strange o_O . Thanks for sharing the knowledge!

Comment: but how to achieve this with Stored Procedure, because stored procedures does not accept without ()