# Passing an array to SQL parameter with Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper, .net-core-3.1

I want to insert into a table an array of values if they don't exist, the array is small and would not exceed 10 items, so it is safe to pass in an insert.

How can I execute this code with Dapper? I tried the following but I am getting an error:

```
const string sqlSymbolsInsert = 
    @"INSERT INTO Country (Name)
        SELECT NewNames.Name FROM (VALUES(@Names)) AS NewNames (Name)
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Country AS C WHERE C.Name = NewNames.Name);";

await using var cn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
await cn.ExecuteAsync(sqlSymbolsInsert, new { Names = countries.Select(x => x.Name) });
```

The error is:

`Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Incorrect syntax near ','.`

There is a similar problem on SO, but it is for the IN clause:
[dapper "IN" clause not working with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31997381/dapper-in-clause-not-working-with-multiple-values)

Is there another way in Dapper to pass an array in my case?

Comment: Why do you expect this would work? SQL has no knowledge of arrays.

Comment: @IanKemp SQL doesn't I agree, but Dapper is solving a similar case, which I linked to.

Comment: Not an array specifically, but it can work [with table valued parameters](https://dapper-tutorial.net/parameter-table-valued-parameter)

Comment: That will result in SQL like `FROM (VALUES((@Names1, @Names2, @Names3)))` as all Dapper does is turn a collection of items into multiple parameters and replaces the single parameter in the query with a comma separated list of those parameters inside of parenthesis, specifically meant to be used for something like `WHERE Name IN @Names`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do isn't possible. But instead of the array, you can just use your `countries` collection. It has a Name property and Dapper will run the query for each item in a suitable collection:

```cs
const string sqlSymbolsInsert = 
    @"INSERT INTO Country (Name)
        SELECT @Name WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    Country 
            WHERE   Name = @Name 
        )";

await using var cn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);
await cn.ExecuteAsync(sqlSymbolsInsert, countries);
```